# What motivated the definition of Theme in Semantics?

Tags: terminology, semantics

<sub>Source: *An Introduction to Language* (10 ed, 2014) by V Fromkin, R Rodman, N Hyams</sub>

> [p 163:] The NP arguments in the VP, which include the subject and any objects, are 
>   semantically related in various ways to the verb. The relations depend on the 
>   meaning of the palticular verb. For example, the NP *the boy* in the sentence:
>
> 1. The boy rolled a red ball.
>      agent       theme
>
> is the "doer" of the rolling action, also called the **agent**. The NP *a red ball* is the 
>   theme or the "undergoer" of the rolling action. [...]
>
> [p 582:] **theme**   The thematic role of the noun phrase whose referent undergoes the action of 
>   the verb:          
>   e.g., *Martha* in George hugged *Martha*.

2. I am confused why the definition of Theme covers only the NP in the predicate: why not the entire VP? What is wrong if I interpret Theme for sentences 1 and 2 as their entire predicates, as follows? The Theme of
   1 is the roll of the red ball
   2 is the hug received by Martha.
3. 2  suggests differences between the ordinary English meaning of 'theme' and the Linguistics meaning. Am I correct? If so, then what motivated Linguistics's selection of this term?

Comment: Because that's how things are. Agent, patient, theme etc. are always expressed by noun phrases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it is inappropriate (not in the sense "rude") to ask about technical terminology drawing on textbooks. Textbooks of necessity simplify. Instead, you should look at scientific works in linguistic and see where concepts first arise and how they are used. I suggest you start with Gruber 1965 (MIT dissertation), which is where the notion was introduced, I believe.

Comment: It's a bad term, and no longer used. Fromkin/Rodman was not a good text, imo, and its terminology is poorly thought out and rarely used today. _Theme_ was a cover term used for any non-agent role like 'undergoer' (now called _patient_). There are a number of such roles, depending on the nature of the predicate; the relation between a verb and its object is extremely variable. This use of _theme_ confuses the pragmatic sense of 'most important topic' with the semantic role of 'patient' and the grammatical role of 'object' without distinguishing them clearly.